# Dynamic Select2 Item Automatically Cleared When New Select2 Is Added In Form?

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-select2-4

I am using Laravel with select2. In my form i am adding select2 dynamically and getting select2 data from server using ajax request and its working fine. But Problem is...

When I select an item from select2 and add new select2 by click on "Add" button, Previous selected item automatically cleared from select2.

Please take a look the problem [jsfiddler](https:////jsfiddle.net/chandanacharjee/Lwdf4s6h/2)

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Select2 Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id='selUser' class="select2_el" style='width: 200px;'>

    </select>

    <div id='elements'>

    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btn_add" value="Add">

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            initailizeSelect2();

            var elem = `<br><select class='select2_el' style='width: 200px;' ></select><br>`;

            $('#btn_add').click(function () {
                $('#elements').append(elem);
                initailizeSelect2();
            });

        });

        // Initialize select2
        function initailizeSelect2() {

            $(".select2_el").select2({
                ajax: {
                    url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            q: params.term, // search term
                            page: params.page
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function (data, params) {
                        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
                        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                        // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
                        // scrolling can be used
                        params.page = params.page || 1;

                        return {
                            results: data.items,
                            pagination: {
                                more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                            }
                        };
                    },
                    cache: true
                },
                placeholder: 'Search for a repository',
                minimumInputLength: 1,
                templateResult: formatRepo,
                templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
            });

            function formatRepo(repo) {
                if (repo.loading) {
                    return repo.text;
                }

                var $container = $(
                    "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>" +
                    "<div class='select2-result-repository__avatar'><img src='" + repo.owner.avatar_url + "' /></div>" +
                    "<div class='select2-result-repository__meta'>" +
                    "<div class='select2-result-repository__title'></div>" +
                    "<div class='select2-result-repository__description'></div>" +
                    "<div class='select2-result-repository__statistics'>" +
                    "<div class='select2-result-repository__forks'><i class='fa fa-flash'></i> </div>" +
                    "<div class='select2-result-repository__stargazers'><i class='fa fa-star'></i> </div>" +
                    "<div class='select2-result-repository__watchers'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> </div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>"
                );

                $container.find(".select2-result-repository__title").text(repo.full_name);
                $container.find(".select2-result-repository__description").text(repo.description);
                $container.find(".select2-result-repository__forks").append(repo.forks_count + " Forks");
                $container.find(".select2-result-repository__stargazers").append(repo.stargazers_count + " Stars");
                $container.find(".select2-result-repository__watchers").append(repo.watchers_count + " Watchers");

                return $container;
            }

            function formatRepoSelection(repo) {
                return repo.full_name || repo.text;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add your code here, we wouldn't chase your code on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize only the newly added select box when clicking the add button. If you initialize the old one again, its value gets lost.

```js
$(".select2_el").select2(
    // ...
)
```

Replace with:

```js
$(".select2_el").not(':has(option:selected)').select2(
    // ...
)
```

Comment: This code is working fine but here have a problem when user post data to server and get validation error, and also bind old data to all select2 control, on that situation Select2 not initialize for this .not(':has(option:selected)'). What should I do?

Comment: @ChandanA. If I understand correctly, the following code will solve your problem `$(".select2_el:not(.initialized)").addClass('initialized').select2(...)`

Comment: It is working fine. Thank you so much Onur Uslu